# Extracting data-reactid with DOM

Tags: dom, domdocument

im trying to scrap a website using dom, but im unable to extract this:

```
<h1 data-reactid="218">
some info
some info
</h1>
```

i've been trying this query, but it doesnt work

```
$allClass = $xpath->query("//h1[@data-reactid='218'");
 foreach ($allClass as $urs) 

{
    foreach ($urs->attributes as $att2)
    {
        print_r($att2->value);
        }
    }
```

Could anyone help me please?

Answer (score 0):

You are missing a closing bracket `]` in your xpath expressions.

Replace this line:

```
$allClass = $xpath->query("//h1[@data-reactid='218'");
```

With this line:

```
$allClass = $xpath->query("//h1[@data-reactid='218']");
```

That will give you:

> 218